# Снова нужна помощь с запятыми. "Он, в отчаянии страшном, будет мстить убийце отца своего"

Tags: пунктуация

"Он, в отчаянии страшном, будет мстить убийце отца своего".
Нужно ли обособлять запятыми "в отчаянии страшном"?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы рассмотрела конструкцию "в отчаянии страшном" как *несогласованное определение* и обособила бы. Относится к личному местоимению: ***он (какой?)*** ***в отчаянии страшном***. Любые определения, относящиеся к личным местоимениям, обособляются.

Comment: Ну вот и славненько)))

Comment: ))))))))))))))))))))))

Answer (score 1):

Можно обособить, если вы имеете в виду "*будучи* в отчаянии страшном". Если нет, то и обособлять не нужно.